# I know that this is French, but

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, user-interface

[image: slight problem]

I know that this is for French, and that proper English isn't going to be the main focus of the site, but this is kind of silly. Could we get the *the* removed?

Comment: Haha... how curious.

Comment: What's in *your* the wallet?

Comment: Thank you, friendly moderators.

Comment: It seems Chinglish :)

Answer (score 3):

Fixed, thanks for bringing it to our attention!

Comment: Thank you very much!